# Why does the Superdraco exhaust seem so under-expanded in this photo?

Tags: spacex, engines, nozzle, super-draco

The Ars Technica articles

- [From zero to 100mph in 1.2 seconds, the SuperDraco thruster delivers](https://arstechnica.com/science/2016/04/meet-spacexs-superdraco-thruster-the-key-to-landing-a-dragon-on-mars/)
- [Dragon was destroyed just before the firing of its SuperDraco thrusters](https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/05/dragon-was-destroyed-just-before-the-firing-of-its-superdraco-thrusters/)

both include this "file photo" [Tweeted by Elon Musk](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/214831794103664640) 2:27 PM - 18 Jun 2012:

> Just fired our Superdraco escape rocket engine at full thrust! Needed to carry astronauts on Dragon

Why does the exhaust look so under-expanded? It looks like it doubles in diameter within a distance of only one diameter, and soon thereafter to a factor of 3 of it's exit diameter.

Doesn't that result in a substantial loss of thrust available to the spacecraft?

**below:** found in [NASA Spaceflight Forum](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=lk41l00uelquoo2btntb2gpog2&topic=33150.msg1119809#msg1119809)

[image: Superdraco first firing twetted]

Comment: It is not uncommon to test rocket engines without the full nozzle installed. Don't know for certain if that's the case here though.

Comment: @Hobbes I don't know anything at all about the image beyond that it's from June 2012 and probably a new result deemed "tweetable" by Elon Musk. You may have the beginnings of the answer.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the mosaic from the same article? there hardly seems to be enough space in the pods for two thrusters plus a big nozzle.

Comment: I was confused about the term 'under-expanded' when the plume was obviously *expanded* horizontally (and we can't conclude much about it's vertical dimensions). Shouldn't that be rephrased?

Comment: @JanDoggen slide 17 https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20140002716.pdf I'm pretty sure the usage is correct. Also see http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/propulsion/q0220.shtml

Comment: Underexpanded is correct. Since the nozzle is too short, the exit plane pressure has not dropped enough (the flow has not *expanded* enough) to match ambient pressure, so the plume has to expand to do so after exiting the nozzle.

Comment: "Twetted" is a great typo

Comment: @ANone thanks for catching that. It'll be there forever in the edit history.

Comment: @JanDoggen its a commonly used term. It refers to the under expansion 'inside the nozzle'. You see it expand afterwards because it didn't expand where it was meant to. The reason this is bad is inside the 'bell' the expansion would generate thrust. This is why the bell is the shape it is.

Comment: Related: [TR-106 underexpansion in sea level test](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22351/tr-106-under-expansion-in-sea-level-test)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [this photo](https://www.spaceflightinsider.com/organizations/space-exploration-technologies/spacexs-superdraco-engine/), the exhaust doesn't expand so much. The nozzle looks to be a bit longer. So they've played with various nozzles.

[image: Superdraco engine test with a nozzle] (cropped and adjusted for visibility)

[image: Superdraco engine test with a nozzle]

And the Ars Technica article has this mosaic, which shows variations in the exhaust (maybe due to throttling?). It also shows how little room there is. The exhaust impinges on the shielding. This seems to be from 2015. The second image in the mosaic shows an exhaust flow that matches the image above pretty well.

[image: Superdraco engine tests]

So it looks like they switched to a slightly longer nozzle later on in the development.

There were more changes during development: in 2013, they switched to a 3D printed combustion chamber.

Comment: @uhoh the heat shield looks pretty flat but it's certainly expending in one axis. Could It be that they use the heatshield as something near a linear aerospike?

Comment: @Christoph that's an interesting idea, you can consider asking it as a new question if you like.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a test-only thing rather than a change in the nozzle design during development.

Answer (score 3):

I think its clear the lack of a nozzle is the cause. As to the "why" I can think of a few reasons that might be partly responsible (other than it's just testing):

- They are not designed to be used for long durations. Mass and TWR are more important relative to ISP than for 'main' engines.
- They need to tuck in for minimum impact on the aero-dynamic profile of the capsule.
- Combustion stability is likely very important and needs to be achieved in a short time. Under expanded nozzles are generally more stable.
- There may (as pointed out) be some nozzling effect from the heat shield and the engine acting in pairs.

All that said, the photo posted does look very under-expanded. More than I would have predicted (but take that for the very little it's worth).